# Docker CMD and WORKDIR getting converted to RUN

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, containers, artifactory

I've created a docker image with Artifactory and Terraform to be used by pods in a K8s Cluster but it wont persist, the pod gets deleted immediately after spinning up and wasn't able to execute the job it was assigned to. Upon checking the pushed image in Artifactory converts the WORKDIR and CMD to RUN, is there anything I'm missing?

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.16.2
LABEL maintainer="Platform Engineering"

# install dependencies
RUN apk add terraform
RUN apk add curl
RUN apk add tree
RUN curl -fL https://install-cli.jfrog.io | sh
RUN curl --location --output /usr/local/bin/release-cli "https://release-cli-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/release-cli-linux-amd64"
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/release-cli

# check version of installed dependencies
RUN terraform -v
RUN jf -v
RUN release-cli -v

# target ci workspace under /tmp directory
WORKDIR /tmp/ci-workspace

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Here's how the layers look like in Artifactory:

[image: Artifactory]

Tried rebuilding in Windows and other machine and installing one binary at a time, nothing worked.

Comment: They turn into _layers_. If your UI says "RUN" for every layer type it doesn't have explicit alternate handling for, the obvious explanation is just sloppy UI development, as opposed to anything that has anything to do with the actual implementation.

Comment: Can you build a question focused on the way running the program in your container fails, instead of focused on the way the Artifactory UI represents that container?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the RUN command that Artifactory shows is a bug in Artifactory. What does `docker history <image name>` show?

Comment: Apologies for framing the question this way but but this is because this is an existing Dockerfile with an image that works but removing some of the extra commands and rebuilding yielded non-functionality.

The same goes for migrated images on the same artifactory but different repositories, docker pull tag push changes CMD and WORKDIR to RUN when on the original repository (in the same artifactory) it doesnt.

Behavior is the original image does what its intended to do but the re-built and migrated images takes the job but doesnt even execute the first line of command.